# Is there are difference between working with Django vs Django on Anaconda

Tags: django, anaconda

I am learning Django and I saw that you can install it regularly, according to the Django documentation. But I also saw that you can work with it in Anaconda. Is there a difference in developing? Or is it all just the same.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _a difference in developing_ ? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anaconda is a distribution on Python that comes with specific versions of a bunch of libraries so that everything is compatible and ready for data science.

So for Django, it will only give you a specific version of it. If you intend to use Anaconda as a framework to do data science, it might be worth it. If you just need Django, just install Django standalone.